# How can I use a CameraView with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax, android-jetpack-compose

Currently there's no equivalent to CameraView (and PreviewView) in Compose. Is it possible to wrap it and display it in a compose layout?

Comment: I haven't tried my self, but there is a sample for webView:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/ui/ui-android-view/src/main/java/androidx/ui/androidview/WebComponent.kt

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/ui/ui-android-view/integration-tests/android-view-demos/src/main/java/androidx/ui/androidview/demos/WebComponentActivity.kt

Comment: May you specify this a bit?

Comment: @pentexnyx I added an answer with more details.

Comment: @HabibKazemi great one (upvoted) - but I was talking to icefex (i didn't mention him though, my bad)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the moment there isn't any official
Composable function for CameraX so we have to inflate the legacy android view inside compose.

To achieve that
we can use `AndroidView` composable function,
it accepts two parameters

- @param `resId` The id of the layout resource to be inflated.
- @param `postInflationCallback` The callback to be invoked after the layout
  is inflated.

and to access the lifecycle and context we use the ambients

```
val lifecycleOwner = LifecycleOwnerAmbient.current
val context = ContextAmbient.current
```

As we have everything we need let's do it:

Create a layout `camera_host.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/previewView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and inflate it using `AndroidView` Composable function.

```
@Composable
fun SimpleCameraPreview() {
    val lifecycleOwner = LifecycleOwnerAmbient.current
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    val cameraProviderFuture = remember { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context) }
    AndroidView(resId = R.layout.camera_host) { inflatedLayout ->
       //You can call
      // findViewById<>() and etc ... on inflatedLayout
      // here PreviewView is the root of my layout so I just cast it to
      // the PreviewView and no findViewById is required

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            bindPreview(
                 lifecycleOwner,
                 inflatedLayout as PreviewView /*the inflated layout*/,
                 cameraProvider)
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))

    }
}

fun bindPreview(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    previewView: PreviewView,
    cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider
) {
    var preview: Preview = Preview.Builder().build()

    var cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        .build()

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider())

    var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SimpleCameraPreview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

There is still no CameraX composable. You need to use `AndroidView` to create one.

Updated example for Compose 1.0.0-beta02:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CameraPreview(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
    scaleType: PreviewView.ScaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER,
) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            val previewView = PreviewView(context).apply {
                this.scaleType = scaleType
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                // Preview is incorrectly scaled in Compose on some devices without this
                implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
            }

            val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)

            cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
                val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                // Preview
                val preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                    }

                try {
                    // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them.
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview
                    )
                } catch (exc: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
                }
            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))

            previewView
        })
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was hoping to find. One question:

`ProcessCameraProvider` appears to be undefined. I've included `androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha3` based on the reference docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/lifecycle/ProcessCameraProvider). What library and version are you using for ProcessCameraProvider? Thanks!

Comment: My dependencies are:

    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-rc04"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-rc04"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha23"

in addition to plenty of other androidx dependencies, but I think those should do it. I would imagine that 1.1.0 would work as well, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks. I just got it working with `1.1.0-alpha03` from Maven and was on my way back to report. What a time to be alive! :)

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.camera/camera-lifecycle

Answer (score 6):

This is my snippet (based on Sean's answer), which also handles torch state and resource disposition and adds a focus on tap logic.
Dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha11'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha31'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha11'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava:1.6.0-RC'
```

```
@Composable
fun CameraPreview(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
    implementationMode: PreviewView.ImplementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE,
    scaleType: PreviewView.ScaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER,
    imageAnalysis: ImageAnalysis? = null,
    imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null,
    preview: Preview = remember { Preview.Builder().build() },
    enableTorch: Boolean = false,
    focusOnTap: Boolean = false
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    val cameraProvider by produceState<ProcessCameraProvider?>(initialValue = null) {
        value = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context).await()
    }

    // TODO: add cameraSelector
    val camera = remember(cameraProvider) {
        cameraProvider?.let {
            it.unbindAll()
            it.bindToLifecycle(
                lifecycleOwner,
                cameraSelector,
                *listOfNotNull(imageAnalysis, imageCapture, preview).toTypedArray()
            )
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(camera, enableTorch) {
        camera?.let {
            if (it.cameraInfo.hasFlashUnit()) {
                it.cameraControl.enableTorch(enableTorch).await()
            }
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier.pointerInput(camera, focusOnTap) {
            if (!focusOnTap) return@pointerInput

            detectTapGestures {
                val meteringPointFactory = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(
                    size.width.toFloat(),
                    size.height.toFloat()
                )

                val meteringAction = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(
                    meteringPointFactory.createPoint(it.x, it.y),
                    FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF
                ).disableAutoCancel().build()

                camera?.cameraControl?.startFocusAndMetering(meteringAction)
            }
        },
        factory = { _ ->
            PreviewView(context).also {
                it.scaleType = scaleType
                it.implementationMode = implementationMode
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(it.surfaceProvider)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks this is really helpful while enabling torch without recomposition!

Answer (score 1):

I've created a library to use CameraX in Jetpack Compose. It might be useful until an official library comes out.

https://github.com/skgmn/CameraXX

In your build.gradle, (requires GitHub personal access token)

```
implementation "com.github.skgmn:cameraxx-composable:0.3.0"
```

Composable method signature

```kotlin
CameraPreview(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
    preview: Preview?,
    imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null,
    imageAnalysis: ImageAnalysis? = null
)
```

You can omit `preview` parameter to use default `Preview` instance.

An example

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
}

@Composable
fun Main() {
    val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
    val imageCapture by remember { viewModel.imageCapture }

    CameraPreview(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), imageCapture)
}
```